# Sorted list of matrices ordered by their determinant in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, sortedlist

I am trying to keep an ordered list of matrices where the ordering is given by the absolute value of the determinant.

To do this I thought about using the *SortedKeyList* object in the *sortedcontainers* package. My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
from sortedcontainers import SortedKeyList

def random_mat(n):
  return np.random.randint(0,5,n*n)

def abs_det(M):
  n = np.int(np.sqrt(len(M)))
  return np.abs(la.det(M.reshape((n,n)))

L = SortedKeyList([random_mat(3): i in range(10)], key=abs_det)

# So far this doesn't give me any issues. Updating the list is the problem:

M = np.array([0,1,2,1,0,2,2,1,0])
L.update(M) #This gives me an error
```

The error appears in the function *abs_det*, it says that it cannot take the length of an integer (numpy.int32), I suspect that when comparing arrays the sorted list is not taking the array as a whole but using the key function entrywise. Originally I tried to use the arrays as matrices with a shape *(n,n)* but when including them in the sorted list the shape would be lost and they were stored as arrays causing other problems when trying to compare them.

A sorted dictionary would not solve the problem as I am interested in taking ranges of the list.

What would be a way to keep a sorted list of matrices ordered by the absolute value of their determinant? Perhaps there is another implementation in *Python* of a sorted list that can deal with these sort of objects?

Comment: What language is that? Doesn't look like Python.

Comment: yeah I got them mixed up when typing the question. I actually used def!

Comment: The expression for `L` also has a syntax error.

Comment: that's a mismatched paren. It would be helpful if you run your reproduction. I'm good though, writing answer now ...

Comment: thank you @KennyOstrom, the code I have is different than the one I typed, I just took part of it for a minimal example. probably that issue does not appear there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SortedKeyList.update is expecting an iterable, so it iterates over all the single integers in M and adds each one to the sorted container.

From the docstring in sortedlist.py

```
def update(self, iterable):
    """Update sorted list by adding all values from `iterable`.
```

It appears to work as you intended if you change that line to

```
L.update([M])
```

The method for adding a single item is add (thanks Kelly Bundy)

```
L.add(M)
```

Comment: It works, thank you @KennyOstrom and Kelly Bundy. that was simpler than I initially thought.